# Focus on an input after div mounted Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I click on a button the modal will show. The modal contains an input field. I want to set the focus to the input field inside the modal when the modal appears after clicking.

This is the button so when I click it the modal shows,

```
<div 
    class="manu-bar-card"
    @click="
       () => {
         groupHandler.addNewgroupModal = true;
         newGroupName.focus();
    }"
 >
```

This is my modal (This will show if `groupHandler.addNewgroupModal` is `true`),

```
<div class="modal-container" v-if="groupHandler.addNewgroupModal">
 <input
        ref="newGroupName"
        type="text"
    />
</div>
```

This is the input field inside the modal I have set a ref attribute to it,

```
<input
    ref="newGroupName"
    type="text"
/>
```

I have registered that ref inside my `<script setup>` and the reactive object to show/hide modal,

```
const newGroupName = ref();
const groupHandler = reactive({
  addNewgroupModal: false,
});
```

I think the reason for not focusing on the input field is modal is not mounted yet when the focus method is called. How to handle such a thing. Appreciate it if somebody could help. Thanks

Comment: Could you show the code of the modal, and how you show and hide it?

Comment: Also, is the modal a separate component?

Comment: Also @Mina I'm willing to make it as a separate component too.

Comment: Why not use the `onMounted` event? [onMounted](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html)

Comment: @RyanWilson Can you explain further? Really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your modal should be a separate component.

Let's call it `<Modal v-if="groupHandler.addNewgroupModal" />`

Inside the `Modal` component, You can make a `ref` for your input, and in the `onMounted` function, you can call `newGroupName.value.focus()`

If you don't want to separate the modal to a saperate component for some reason.

You can use `nextTick`

```
<div 
    class="manu-bar-card"
    @click="clickHandler"
 >
```

And in the `setup` script.

```
<div 
    class="manu-bar-card"
    @click="
       () => {
         groupHandler.addNewgroupModal = true;
         newGroupName.focus();
    }"
 >
```

And in your `setup` script.

```
import { nextTick } from 'vue'

const clickHandler = async () => {
  groupHandler.addNewgroupModal = true;
  await nextTick()
  newGroupName.value.focus();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the idea but is it possible to do it the way I have stated in the question. It is really easy to do with jQuery but not Vue why?

Comment: Yes, you can use `nextTick`, I just update my answer, please check.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you explain me what this nextTick() really do

Comment: You are welcome, Vuejs works with batch state update, that's mean `groupHandler.addNewgroupModal = true;` doesn't immediately will show the `modal`, but it will wait until the current state cycle to update the UI, So `nextTick` will not execute the code after until the UI update ( the modal shown )

Comment: For more resources, you can read this article. https://dmitripavlutin.com/vue-next-tick/